# Is there any Namespace or Package in Any Language that Check English Grammar Check

Tags: logic, nlp, languagetool

I want to make many large software systems which requires the functions that have features like English Grammar Check and all other validations/manipulations that can be done in English. Is there any package available in any programming language that gives me these resources? Just imagine I am making a software like MSword, and I want to add Grammar Validations in my software same as in MSword, is there anything available or I have to code everything from scratch? How hard it would be according to you? How much time would it take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [LanguageTool for Java](http://wiki.languagetool.org/java-api). It supports many languages including English and you can add your own rules. Just don't expect the check to be perfect; Word's isn't either.